# Mapping pandas DataFrame values in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, mapping

I want to take `df` below and map its columns `fruit` and `dessert` into a JSON file.

```
#df
fruit       dessert
-------------------
apple       sauce
blueberry   muffin
cherry      pie

import json
df = df.to_json()

#desired output
{"apple": "sauce", "blueberry": "muffin", "cherry": "pie"}
```

I have imported what I needed and converted `df` to JSON. What should I do next to get the output desired?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create dictionary by `zip` and `dict` and then convert to `json`:

```
import json

j = json.dumps(dict(zip(df['fruit'], df['dessert'])))
print (j)
{"apple": "sauce", "blueberry": "muffin", "cherry": "pie"}
```

Or create `Series` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and call [`Series.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

```
j = df.set_index('fruit')['dessert'].to_json()
print (j)
{"apple":"sauce","blueberry":"muffin","cherry":"pie"}
```

Comment: not sure what happened but after running the code a couple times I am now getting this error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers` What could it be?

Comment: @mattebeat - What code return error? Because if need mapping in python need `dict`, not json, so use `d = dict(zip(df['fruit'], df['dessert']))` or `d = df.set_index('fruit')['dessert'].to_json()`

Comment: first one gives me this `TypeError: string indices must be integers` 
second one gives me this `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set_index'`

Comment: @mattebeat - What is `print (df)` ? It is `DataFrame`, if test `print (type(df))` ?

Comment: yes it returns as
`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: okay it is working now! still not sure what happened but i will just leave it as is. thanks again!

Comment: @mattebeat -  I ask because error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set_index'` means `df` is not DataFrame, but string. So is possible test `print (type(df))` before `df.set_index('fruit')['dessert'].to_json()` ? Because it seems use something like `df = df.set_index('fruit')['dessert'].to_json()` - so variable `df` is converted to string json, so If use again `df.set_index('fruit')['dessert'].to_json()` `df` is not Dataframe, but string., so raised error

Answer (score 1):

You can reindex and use .to_dict

```
df.set_index('fruit').to_dict()['dessert']
```

Comment: OP need convert values to json, not to dict.

Comment: JSON is a dictionary subset.